# How to configure single sign on with Sustainsys Saml2 for multiple service providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sustainsys-saml2

We have two Service Providers and one Identity Provider. When we configure both Service Providers to use the same Identity Provider the behaviour is as follows:

- User requests page on Service Provider A
- User is being redirected to Identity Provider
- User logs in
- User is being redirected to Service Provider A
- On Service Provider A there is a link to Service Provider B
- User is being redirected to Identity Provider
- **User have to login again**
- User is being redirected to Service Provider B

***How to configure Sustainsys in such a way the second login is not necessary?***

We created a sample based on the code in https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2. For the Identity Provider we use the StupIdp of the supplied code. For the Service Provider we use the SampleMvcApplication.

Web.config of service provider A:

```
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId="http://localhost:2181/Saml2" returnUrl="http://localhost:2181/" >
    <identityProviders>
        <add entityId="http://localhost:52071/Metadata" signOnUrl="http://localhost:52071/" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
            <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/stubidp.sustainsys.com.cer"/>
        </add>
    </identityProviders>
    <federations>
        <add metadataLocation="http://localhost:52071/Federation" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"/>
    </federations>
    <serviceCertificates>
        <add fileName="~/App_Data/Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx"/>
    </serviceCertificates>
</sustainsys.saml2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The stub idp does not feature single sign on. It doesn't keep track of any kind of session.

If you connect to a real Idp, you will be automatically signed in to the second SP (given that the Idp is configured to support it)